# enable step up converter based on low voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I recently built step up converter which work quite good.
Now I would like to build a circuit which would enable this step up converter when battery voltage drops below 1.8V (Arduino BOD).

- I need to keep in mind power consumption because of battery power

Now, I do not know what is the best method to do that.

I guess that couple of transistors would do the job but I do not know where to start.
Also I dont know if it is optimal solution bacouse of battery power.

> The EN pin is a logic-level input used to enable or disable device switching and lower quiescent current while disabled. A logic high (>70%of VIN) will enable the regulator output. A logic low (<20% of VIN) will ensure that the regulator is disabled.

So if I understand it correctly, I need "circuit" that will "bring" VIN on EN pin when VIN < 1.8 V.

Please give me some direction to start with this.
Thank you.

EDIT 2017-03-07 I went search in direction mentioned in comments and found this [video](https://youtu.be/y0Q0ERSP24A). Which I guess is good start.

p.s. Iam using MCP1625 which has enable pin.

Comment: Basically its factory recommended design of MCP1625 discussed here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236184/step-up-converter-voltage-drop-on-load.

Comment: The solution will include a reference, a divisor, and some type of comparator to drive the boost enable. If cost is not a concern, you can find all of this in a single IC which is targeted at this sort of application.

Comment: How many cells in series are you using for this? 1 alkaline?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 right now in my prototype I went for CR123A because of its size. Alternatively I would use two AA bateries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you won't be able to squeese out so much energy of the battery when it is almost empty.

Anyhow you could either use a low voltage comparator with a reference, like this:

[image]

Change the resistors accordingly for your application. You might want to invert the output with an NPN transistor and a pullup.

Or you could build something with transistors. I don't know if this actually works in the "real" world but it works in my LTSpice simulation:

[image]

Q1 holds EN low until VBAT reaches approximately 1.8 V when it releases EN to VBAT. The trip point can be adjusted by changing R5 and R4. R7 provides a bit of hysteresis around the trip point. I'm mediocre at designing transistor circuits so I would definitively go with the IC version.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is what I was looking for. I use 3V battery and BOD is around 1.8 V. That is 60% of battery would be vasted. Transistor circuit is impressive, but I will go with IC. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a comparator circuit to measure when the battery voltage drops below 1.8V, then have this toggle the EN pin?

Comment: But how do I get reference for OA when voltage is changing in time.. Divider would return slightly different values each time.

Comment: You can use a reference voltage chip, and have the divider set against that, or you can get some type of comparator chip with a built in low reference voltage. Seems the guy above me answered pretty extensively though, and that IC he mentioned will do the trick nicely!